# JTidy and XHTML 1.1: is it possible?

Tags: xhtml, doctype, tidy, jtidy, xhtml-1.1

I need to transform HTML into XHTML 1.1.

I'm doing it in a Java program, so I decided to use JTidy. But if you tell JTidy to transform output in XHTML, you get XHTML 1.0, not XHTML 1.1. I've found some posts on Google about Tidy and XHTML 1.1 from 2003 and earlier, but I'm not able to find any option for XHTML 1.1 with JTidy.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JTidy worked with XHTML 1.0, it should definitely work with XHTML 1.1.

The [only changes between XHTML 1.0 and XHTML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/changes.html):

> 1. On the `a` and `map` elements, the `name`
>      attribute has been removed in favor
>      of the `id` attribute (as defined in
>      [[XHTMLMOD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/references.html#ref_xhtml_modularization)]).
> 2. The "`ruby`" collection
>      of elements has been added (as
>      defined in [[RUBY](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/references.html#ref_ruby)]).

Comment: Either I don't get the question or the answer. I thought that the issue is that tidy always return 1.0. How to make it return 1.1?